# Windows 10 Taskbar replacement

Tags: windows-10

Best to be open source.

Implement most Windows 10 taskbar functions and:

The current taskbar is alwasy full...headache to decide which windows to close to make space for more windows.

Overflow/multi desktop can never compare with a single taskbar with all buttons (dozens of them) there concurrently.

When the taskbar is on the left/right of the desktop:

(1) Can config the height of button. Currently there is only two choices: big icon and small icon. Customizable ultrasmall icon needed.

(2) Multi column. Currently only multi row on the bottom/top is supported. When the taskbar is on the left/right, there is no such options.

(3) Remove start menu which can be bring up by WinKey.

(4) Config the date time and input method button. Now it is not configurable when at left/right of the desktop. Now it alwasy takes 4 row with spaces between datatime and IM which is a huge space waste.